# How do I handle "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: wordpress

How do I handle "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 49152 bytes) in /home/ezzy0881/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/Item.php on line 662"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the amount of memory allocated to WP. In your wp-config.php file, add `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );`. wp-config.php should be editable within the admin. Otherwise, get FTP access and you'll find the config file in the root of you site.